# How to find out my IP address from previous days

Tags: networking, log, ip

I would like to have a list of all the IP addresses my network card has had in the last days (hopefully at least a week).

Is there a place where it might be logged those records, saying, for instance, that my network interface is `eth0`? (It is not, it is a long hexadecimal number)

Comment: If you obtain an IP address via DHCP, you could `zgrep DHCPACK /var/log/syslog*`

Comment: This [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/944687/how-to-see-what-dhcp-client-does) will help you about DHCP Clients.